# Getting odd color pattern while implementing ESRGAN

Tags: generative-adversarial-network

I'm implementing ESRGAN on PyTorch. However, I'm getting some weird color pattern, and the result does not seem better than the low-resolution picture. What could possibly be the cause of this? Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code of the network my first thought is that you should check the post-processing of the image. Maybe values are getting clipped somewhere, or denormalized incorrectly.

Also look at images over different checkpoints of training. Is the artifact consistent? When did it appear?

Comment: Hello Karl, I added results after some certain epochs. The odd color pattern exists in every result since epoch 1, only in different colors.